# Samsung galaxy s3 being slow and getting hot

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I have a samsung galaxy s3 running Android 4.3, and it's always really slow and gets very hot sometimes. Does anyone elses phone do this? If so, have you found anything that helps?

Comment: Take a look in the battery settings, and tell us if any apps are using a high percentage of your battery.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends the way you use your phone(more no of dents rough and tough use), The no of years of service of your battery.(the last time you changed your battery as recommended). Just follow these steps

1. Just try to avoid pro-longed usage of the device for gaming or
   streaming videos or doing multi-tasking(streaming high definition
   videos, parallel texting and downloading content all at once)
2. As this tends the battery to get heated up. Normally it should not
   get the heat for just 1-1.5 hours of gaming
3. If your usage is more then you need to reduce it or else just
   take your cell phone to any authorised Service Centre and get you
   phone checked for the problems of heat and battery